# The hosts process namespace should not be shared by containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

Im trying to understand what this issue is about, i get a link to docker documentation but it mentions pids(Process ID) and does nothing for me in helping me understand what its about. so what does this pertain to in where i need add this into my compose file and what its meant for/does. The error-> "The hosts process namespace should not be shared by containers" and has a description of "There is no pid declared" and refers to line 39 my_api: and line 5 my_db:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  my_db:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    container_name: my_db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "${DB_USERNAME}"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
      POSTGRES_DB: "${DB_NAME}"
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5432:${DB_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    networks:
      - db

  my_api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      posts_db:
        condition: service_healthy
    container_name: my_api
    platform: linux/amd64/v8
    environment:
      CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT: local_docker

      DB_HOST: "${DB_HOST}"
      DB_PORT: "${DB_PORT}"
      DB_NAME: "${DB_NAME}"
      DB_USERNAME: "${DB_USERNAME}"
      DB_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"


    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - /app/database
      - ./:/app
    networks:
      - api
      - db
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD",
          "wget",
          "-q",
          "http://localhost:8000/api/health_check/cluster",
          "-O",
          "/dev/null"
        ]

networks:
  api:
  db:
```

ive read into documentation about pid and i think its meant to set a namespace for the different containers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How is this question related to python or - more general - programming or software engineering?

Comment: Please add the following to your question: 1) your compose file 2) the full text of the error/output you are getting, including a full stack trace if present 3) a complete description of the issue, including what you are trying to accomplish and what you are doing to cause the error to occur.

Comment: Ive added from my docker-compose.yml file and as for the error/output this issue is coming from an SAST tool and the only output i have is "The hosts process namespace should not be shared by containers" and "There is no pid declared".

Comment: The Compose file you included doesn't seem to do anything to try to change pid namespaces, though.

Comment: @DavidMaze can you possible link me to doc that can expand on this, im not sure what the purpose of this is.

Comment: Compose has a [`pid:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#pid) setting that can change a container to use the host process ID namespace; but you're not using that, so I can't tell why you'd be getting a complaint about it.